# MEF Directory catalog

Tags: c#, .net, mef

i have a solution with the following Structure:

project.Model

project.Builder

project.Unit Tests

in the builder project it should create a Model instance using MEF.
so in the Builder class constructor i want it to have a container to hold the parts related to building the model only(as a separation of concerns) .

currently i am using the directory catalog as follows:

```
var path = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
var catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(path + @"\Builder\bin\Debug");
```

so that in the unit test project i can use this container in writing the unit tests functions.
is there a better way to make the builder container have only the dlls that resides in the builder project output directory (bin\debug).
I have tried using:

```
var directory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
var catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(directory);
```

bu this have make the catalog to scan the output directory of the unit tests projects which have made a lot of problems other than being not where I want the catalog to scan.

is there a more correct way than what I'm currently doing ?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use and [AssemblyCatalog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.assemblycatalog(v=vs.110).aspx) - and add a static reference from Builder project to Model project, so you can avoid all problems with folders - scanning the whole folder, directory structure change during deployment, different versions of assembly in the same folder, etc.
The code would look something like

```
var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(YourModelType).Assembly);
```